# HowTo build boost with debug libstdc++ on linux (GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag)

Tags: c++, boost, g++, b2

I try to build boost with following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$BUILD_PATH" ]
then
    echo "Variable BUILD_PATH isn't specified!"
    exit
fi

BOOST_BUILD_PATH="$BUILD_PATH/boost"
mkdir "$BOOST_BUILD_PATH"

NBITS=64
STAGEDIR="$BOOST_BUILD_PATH"
PLATF_AUX="architecture=x86 address-model=64"
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=$(nproc)
SPEZ_DEFS="-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG"



./bootstrap.sh
./b2 -j$NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS --toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=c++14,-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG cflags=-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG variant=release,debug link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi \
            --with-locale -s ICU_PATH=$BUILD_PATH/icu \
            --with-system --with-atomic --with-timer --with-thread --with-chrono --with-program_options --with-filesystem --with-date_time --with-regex --with-iostreams \
            -s NO_ZLIB=0 -s ZLIB_INCLUDE=../BUILD/zlib/include -s ZLIB_LIBPATH=$BUILD_PATH/zlib/lib -s NO_BZIP2=1 \
            --stagedir=$STAGEDIR debug-symbols=on $PLATF_AUX --layout=tagged stage
```

I don't know how to thoroughly check that boost is compiled with correct flags. Obvoiusly, it is not, since I get such errors from building libs that depend on boost:

```
In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
/path/to/project/../../shared/boost/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__debug::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
```

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160933/segfault-when-using-boostsignal-with-d-glibcxx-debug-compiler-flag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729036/boost-program-options-wont-work-with-glibcxx-debug) it's mentioned that boost can be compiled with debug libstdc++. But how?

Comment: Why do you compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`?

Comment: It enables debug assert checks in stdlibc++ like range checks for vector.